# SQL: [table_name] AS [alias_name] gives error "Could not find stored procedure 'table_name'"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table alias in order to make my SQL code more readable. Currently I have a very long table name which I want to give an alias. Not sure if it makes a difference but I only have read access to the table that I am trying to create an alias for. Any other ways that I can accomplish what I am trying to do?

EDIT:
EDIT2 (A small mistake with "order" not changed to "orderName")

```
ALL_THE_CUSTOMER_NAMES AS NAMES
ALL_THE_PRODUCTS_IN_THE_STORE AS PRODUCTS

SELECT 
    NAMES.meaning AS meaning,
    PRODUCTS.orderName AS orderName,
    PRODUCTS.publishedDate AS oldDate, 
    PRODUCTS.dueDate AS paymentDate, 
    COUNT(*) AS numberCount, 
    AMOUNT AS AMOUNT,
    DATEDIFF(d, PRODUCTS.publishedDate, PRODUCTS.dueDate) as dateDifference,
    orderType as Fordringstype
FROM PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN NAMES
on PRODUCTS.ID = NAMES.ID
WHERE 
    (PRODUCTS.customerID = 1 
    or 
    PRODUCTS.customerID = 2)
    and
    PRODUCTS.orderType = 'CARS'
    and
    PRODUCTS.orderName NOT IN ('BLUE', 'RED')
GROUP BY 
    PRODUCTS.orderName,
    PRODUCTS.publishedDate,
    PRODUCTS.dueDate,
    PRODUCTS.AMOUNT,
    PRODUCTS.orderType,
    NAMES.meaning
Order BY PRODUCTS.publishedDate
```

Comment: Hi, Please show us the query

Comment: Guessing from your title: The syntax isn't `FROM TableName [AS] TN`, you don't quote the `AS`, you quote the object names. So, the correct syntax would be `FROM [TableName] AS [TN]` or `FROM TableName AS TN`. You alias a Table, with the `AS` clause, exactly like you would with a column in your `SELECT`.

Comment: @Larnu Nice deduction skills. Have you done tech support previously?

Comment: Thanks for the syntax help for the question title - I am not that familiar with SQL. However, this is exactly what I already wrote.

Comment: @BenjaminAndersen, then why don't you show us *exactly what you wrote*?

Comment: @JacobH no, but I'm far too used to the users we have in the office. For example, more than often, "My computer is broken!!!" means "The printer has run out of paper, and i can't print." -_-

Comment: There is no more to show. It says that "Could not find stored procedure for [table_name] even before I start using the alias. So showing the code where I use the alias is quite redundant since it already works without the alias.

Comment: Share the code that gives the problem. Otherwise, nobody can offer any solution for you.

Comment: But we can't see your screen. You have code that works and code that doesn't work. Obviously something is different between them. Why not just post the query instead of defending your decision to make it more difficult for others to help.

Comment: You don't, hopefully, just have `table_name as alias_name` as the entirety of your query. (Because if you do, that should report a syntax error at `as`). Aliases are introduced as *part* of a larger query. And the one thing for sure is that, as *part* of a query, SQL Server shouldn't be thinking that something is a stored procedure name (since they cannot be composed into queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put the aliases of tables at the top of your SQL; SQL doesn't work like a declarative language. Like I said in the comments:

> You alias a Table, with the `AS` clause, exactly like you would with a column in your `SELECT`

So, the correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT 
    NAMES.meaning AS meaning,
    PRODUCTS.orderName AS orderName,
    PRODUCTS.publishedDate AS oldDate, 
    PRODUCTS.dueDate AS paymentDate, 
    COUNT(*) AS numberCount, 
    AMOUNT AS AMOUNT,
    DATEDIFF(d, PRODUCTS.publishedDate, PRODUCTS.dueDate) as dateDifference,
    orderType as Fordringstype
FROM ALL_THE_PRODUCTS_IN_THE_STORE AS PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN ALL_THE_CUSTOMER_NAMES AS NAMES ON PRODUCTS.ID = NAMES.ID
WHERE 
    (PRODUCTS.customerID = 1 
    or 
    PRODUCTS.customerID = 2)
    and
    PRODUCTS.orderType = 'CARS'
    and
    PRODUCTS.orderName NOT IN ('BLUE', 'RED')
GROUP BY 
    PRODUCTS.orderName,
    PRODUCTS.publishedDate,
    PRODUCTS.dueDate,
    PRODUCTS.AMOUNT,
    PRODUCTS.orderType,
    NAMES.meaning
Order BY PRODUCTS.publishedDate;
```

Any questions, please do ask.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu! Sorry for me being a bit slow there. But I get it now!

Comment: @BenjaminAndersen You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
Select columnname from tablename alias...
```